# MAUI application on VS for Mac fails to launch on iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, deployment, maui, simulator, launch

I have a quite complex MAUI application that nicely deploys and runs on Mac Catalyst, Windows and Android. Despite I configured anything related to the bundle signing (and stuff like these) in the project's iOS settings, I keep on receiving this error on Application Output window while launching on iOS Simulator:

xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/dev/ttys000 --stderr=/dev/ttys003 --terminate-running-process 9301D251-1BD6-402B-BC92-563146ECD5BD com.improveforinnovation.semplice -monodevelop-port 10000
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
Application launch for 'com.improveforinnovation.semplice' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error.
No such process
error HE0042: Could not launch the app 'com.improveforinnovation.semplice' on the device 'iOS 16.2 (20C52) - iPhone 14 Pro': simctl returned exit code 3

The application then immediately crashes.

I tried several suggested solutions, such as:

- "Erase all content and settings..." on Simulator
- Clear bin and obj folders in my solution
- Change bundle identifier (both on XCode and app's info.plist)

Still I can't figure it out how to get back to a normal deployment.
Moreover, running a sample MAUI application (such as the one VS provides when you first start with MAUI), works perfectly on Simulator.
The XCode (and CLT) version installed is 14.2 (14C18) and I'm attaching the information about the entire environment.

Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac Preview
Version 17.5 Preview (17.5 build 1741)
Installation UUID: 3bad68d7-d24b-4f2f-897b-27b96c61a486

Runtime
.NET 7.0.1 (64-bit)
Architecture: Arm64
Microsoft.macOS.Sdk 12.3.2372; git-rev-head:754abbf6a3563f6267e5717ae832b4ac25b1f2fb; git-branch:release/7.0.1xx-xcode13.3

Roslyn (Language Service)
4.5.0-3.23056.2+97881342e427ff5cdcba8f12b12ff8e6f3564431

NuGet
Version: 6.4.0.117

.NET SDK (Arm64)
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.200-preview.22628.1/Sdks
SDK Versions:
7.0.200-preview.22628.1
7.0.101
7.0.100
6.0.405
6.0.404
6.0.403
6.0.402
6.0.401
6.0.400
6.0.400-preview.22330.6
6.0.301
6.0.300
6.0.203
MSBuild SDKs: /Applications/Visual Studio (Preview).app/Contents/MonoBundle/MSBuild/Current/bin/Sdks

.NET SDK (x64)
SDK Versions:
3.1.426
3.1.425
3.1.424
3.1.423
3.1.422
3.1.421
3.1.420
3.1.419

.NET Runtime (Arm64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
7.0.1
7.0.0
6.0.13
6.0.12
6.0.11
6.0.10
6.0.9
6.0.8
6.0.6
6.0.5

.NET Runtime (x64)
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
3.1.32
3.1.31
3.1.30
3.1.29
3.1.28
3.1.27
3.1.26
3.1.25

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.8.0.49
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode: 14.2 21534
Build: 14C18

Xamarin.Mac
Not Installed

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 16.2.0.2 Visual Studio Community
Hash: 956a059ba
Branch: xcode14.2
Build date: 2022-12-15 06:15:44-0500

Xamarin Designer
Version: 17.5.3.46
Hash: e4dd80b2bb
Branch: remotes/origin/d17-5
Build date: 2023-01-25 00:18:10 UTC

Xamarin.Android
Version: 13.2.0.0 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d17-5/797e2e1
Android SDK: /Users/******************/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
Supported Android versions:
12.0 (API level 31)
13.0 (API level 33)

SDK Command-line Tools Version: 7.0
SDK Platform Tools Version: 33.0.2
SDK Build Tools Version: 33.0.0

Build Information:
Mono: 6dd9def
Java.Interop: xamarin/java.interop/main@149d70fe
SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.40.0@fdc1e34
Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/main@9f02d77

Microsoft Build of OpenJDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/microsoft-11.jdk
11.0.16.1
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Eclipse Temurin JDK
Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-8.jdk
1.8.0.302
Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android SDK Manager
Version: 17.5.0.26
Hash: 2eaa6bb
Branch: remotes/origin/HEAD
Build date: 2023-01-25 00:18:16 UTC

Android Device Manager
Version: 0.0.0.1236
Hash: bd1b161
Branch: main~1
Build date: 2023-01-25 00:18:16 UTC

Build Information
Release ID: 1705001741
Git revision: baaf93527ad3efd87886b9b81bf5d6871f8ac51d
Build date: 2023-01-25 00:16:06+00
Build branch: release-17.5
Build lane: release-17.5

Operating System
Mac OS X 13.2.0
Darwin 22.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.3.0
Thu Jan  5 20:49:43 PST 2023
root:xnu-8792.81.2~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103 arm64

Is there any idea about the reason why I'm stuck with this error and on how to get out of it?

Comment: Try to remove the app from simulator if it's already installed.
Close VS. Delete obj+bin folder. Open VS rebuild. Try again.

Comment: * Make a new app from Maui template. Build and run. Same symptom? * Factory reset the simulator. * To be really sure you get a clean build, download the sources from your source repo to a new folder.

Comment: Have you tried a different simulator? Or remove the simulator and then add a new one in XCode?

Comment: Also find a similar issue on Github. Is it help?[Unable to deploy to iOS 15.4 emulator #14834](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/14834)

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas, already tried with no luck.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve 1 - with a new MAUI template it doesn't occur. 2 - already tried with no luck. 3 - tried several times as well, but nothing new.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I tried both with another simulator with no success and reinstalling all simulators, no luck at all.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT as you can see by the details in the question, I am using this version of Xamarin.iOS:
Version: 16.2.0.2 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 956a059ba
Branch: xcode14.2
Build date: 2022-12-15 06:15:44-0500 with no chance to rollback to v. 15 as suggested on GitHub.

Comment: Create a new project. Verify it deploys. Add all the nugets you use. Verify it deploys. Set your bundle id, and any other configuration changes you have. Verify it deploys. Compare the csproj and nuget versions to the failing project. If any differences, try to resolve. If can't resolve, copy that project folder elsewhere (so you can get back to it if needed). Add all your source code to that new project. Success?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was running into these same errors with our .net iOS application which we are working on moving over to net6.0-ios from xamarinios. Trying to run on the simulator on an M1 mac gave errors.

```
xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/dev/ttys001 --stderr=/dev/ttys002
--terminate-running-process 8CFC6FE4-MY-GUID-ABCDEFG com.mycompany.mobile -monodevelop-port 10000 
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3): 
Application launch for 'com.mycompany.mobile' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error. No such process
```

and

```
error HE0042: Could not launch the app 'com.mycompany.mobile' on the device 'iOS 16.2 (20C52) - iPhone 14': simctl returned exit code 3
```

Somewhere along the way `<RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>` got added to my debug and release configurations in the iOS csproj file. I removed them and I can now run our app in the simulator.