# While launching MAUI App, it is crashing on iPhone (device and Emulator)

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, maui, visual-studio-2022

I have been getting error while launching the MAUI application on iPhone (Emulator and device) using visual studio 2022, however, it is working fine on Android and even in Mac Catalyst. App successfully gets installed into the iPhone but while launching the App, it gets crashed and I am also unable to stop on a debug breakpoint. while crashing visual studio is throwing an error below:

```
xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/dev/ttys000 --stderr=/dev/ttys001 --terminate-running-process C1CA7C90-F46F-42DA-8357-08893E0E94E9 com.anglianhome.footcan -monodevelop-port 10000
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
No such process
Underlying error (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=3):
    Application launch for 'com.anglianhome.footcan' did not return a valid pid nor a launch error.
    No such process
error HE0042: Could not launch the app 'com.anglianhome.footcan' on the device 'iOS 16.4 (20E247) - iPhone 14': simctl returned exit code 3
```

Need help resolving that, please.

Comment: hey OP, were you able to resolve this? I'm facing the same error

Answer (score 1):

Check your Debug and Release configuration inside your .csproj file.

I found [this
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75347469/maui-application-on-vs-for-mac-fails-to-launch-on-ios-simulator) where Visual Studio added `<RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>` at some point. Removing this entry should fix it!